# How to insert \n within a string

Tags: zsh, bourne-shell

I'm generating a private key, this key is for demonstrable purposes only:

```
$ openssl genrsa

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAvB8fZFRS83Kztend5KO9cnWXaqLWot0qLDeLcS8ly718FUdm
3VcCY5j737zz4iwmFf3b20Q2XxlbYC/M13wTJzHBf2d1mRDlpZq7CgX/JSEUW/Hr
uXiF6PI+ypkvskyoQcz04rlT8skd7tanXhXINnLwW7gCiNlxQQFkrpfO8Fkh+vYL
...
Ewac3GAh9CiMikQEYNxpsuLLboS4NcaQWiGB+1imtPtbp8Gf89pJSVBDubgza2Bb
rucNxP3HZtPd6G9CvkMJREYL7jHkXYa5DBzs9LB9mLB4b5H/6KN/fsfj
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

There is a newline `\n` at the end of each of these lines that needs removing, I want everything on a single line so I can set it to an env var. Note: I'm unable to store a multiline env var in `.env` as `docker-compose` doesn't support it.

I've stripped out all the new lines with this:

```
$(openssl genrsa | tr -d '\n')

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MII...-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I then manually insert two newlines `\n` which I'm looking to automate through a script (hence this post). If I don't do this the signing of the JWT fails.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMII...\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I define it within a `.env` file

```
JWT_PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMII...\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

With node and [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) I access it like so:

```
privateRsaKey = process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/gm, '\n'),
```

Now `privateRsaKey` looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MII...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now I actually use the private key to sign a [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

```
const signed = jwt.sign(payload, privateRsaKey, { 
  algorithm: 'RS256',
  ...
});
```

All of the above is working as expected when I bring up the Docker containers.

**I need help in the scripting so I don't have to manually insert two `\n`**

Thank you all for you help and patience it's much appreciated.

Comment: env vars can contain newlines alright. The only character they can't contain is NUL. `zsh` variables don't even have that limitation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm using `dotenv` with `docker-compose` and it doesn't like multiline strings (moaning about spaces even though there aren't any), however, it accepts a single line formatted as per my example.

Comment: Support newlines in env files: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3527

Comment: Your title and question body do not match: Title says insert, body says remove.

Comment: Is your question "How do I replace a newline character with a literal `\n`?"

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I've just edited the main body, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you just replace newlines with `\n`, the result is ambiguous, because `\n` could have been either a newline or `\n` in the original. It isn't a problem in this specific case because the input won't contain `\n`, but it would be a problem for many other cases, including some PEM formats that can contain comments where `\n` is allowed.

A common way to pass data through a transport mechanism (in your case, getting it into your Docker container) is to encode it as Base64. The Base64 encoding only includes ASCII letters (uppercase and lowercase), digits and the three punctuation characters `+/=`. Whitespace is not significant. To encode without newlines:

```
private_key="$(openssl genrsa)"
export encoded_private_key="$(printf '%s\n' "$private_key" | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

To decode:

```
private_key=$(echo "$encoded_private_key" | base64 -d)
```

or

```
echo "$encoded_private_key" | base64 -d >private_key.pem
```

Comment: But `base64` (at least the one from GNU coreutils) wraps long lines, so you'll still end up with newlines in there unless you do `openssl genrsa | base64 -w0` (still assuming GNU `base64`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh, yes, thanks. I forgot to remove the newlines.

Comment: Ironically the output of `openssl genrsa` is already the base64 encoding of the key. So if you did `openssl genrsa | grep -v '^---' | tr -d '\n'`, you'd end up with *only* the base64 encoding of they key, which you could still use with `base64 -d | openssl rsa -inform der` for instance.

Comment: Note that `openssl` can do base64 encoding as well (`openssl enc -a` or `openssl base64`) which would allow you to remove the extra dependency on a separate `base64` utility. `openssl enc -a -A` to remove the need for `tr -d '\n'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas True. But I prefer to use more generic tools in my answer so that it's applicable for cases other than a key that has been freshly generated by `openssl`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thanks for the pointer. I've taken this approach and have everything working. I wrote a bash script that essentially writes both public/private keys to seperate pem files. In the script I derive the public key from the private key and then read both files into variables, I then base64 encode both of them, the result echo'd to the console, finally, I delete both pem files. When reading both env vars in I simply decode them on node.js like so: `Buffer.from(key, 'base64').toString()`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Shell gurus will make it simpler but here's my take:

```bsh
openssl genrsa 2>/dev/null | awk '{ if ($0~"BEGIN RSA") {ORS="\\n"; print} else {if ($0~"END RSA") {print "\\n"; print} else {ORS=""; print}}}'

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIE....skipped
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Produces exactly what you want.

Comment: Apologies if my post is not clear enough. The output must be a single line that includes two `\n`.

Comment: @gainy I've edited the answer, so that it output `\n` instead of a new line.

Comment: Thanks for that, everything is now on a single line, unfortunately, the very last character is a `%` - not sure where that is coming from. **Maybe a shell guru can come to the rescue**.

Comment: @gainy, the `%` is likely zsh telling you the output doesn't end in a newline character. It doesn't matter if you're going to store it in a variable with something like `var=$(that command line)` as `$(...)` removes all trailing newline characters anyway.